# Little, unknown, English or French research journals with good mathematics

Tags: soft-question, big-list, online-resources, publishing, research

In [this article by Gian-Carlo Rota](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~cahn/life/gian-carlo-rota-10-lessons.html#publish), you can read:

> "I bought a copy of Frederick Riesz' *Collected Papers* as soon as the
>   big thick heavy oversize volume was published. [...] It was clear that
>   Riesz' publications were few. What is more surprising is that the
>   papers had been published several times. Riesz would publish the first
>   rough version of an idea in some obscure Hungarian journal. A few
>   years later, he would send a series of notes to the French Academy's
>   Comptes Rendus in which the same material was further elaborated. A
>   few more years would pass, and he would publish the definitive paper,
>   either in French or in English."

This made me wonder if nowadays there are some (printed or online) ***research journals*** (in *English* or *French*) that are somewhat *obscure* (*note*: I don't mean "obscure because their target audience is composed by few specialists") and nevertheless publish good works by good mathematicians.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Functiones et Approximatio, Commentarii Mathematici*](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~fa/) is off most of the published lists of journals. Nevertheless it is a serious journal for refereed papers in mathematical research, with a 40-year history of continuous publication. Based in Poznan, Poland, it publishes, in English, papers in analysis and number theory. Among the well-known authors whose papers it has featured is Roger Heath-Brown.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point might be archive.org with a lot of historical mathematical texts:

- [Kalkül der abzählenden Geometrie](https://archive.org/details/kalklderabzh00schuuoft) (Schubert)
- [Vorlesungen über die Theorie der automorphen Functionen](https://archive.org/details/vorlesungenber01fricuoft) (Fricke+Klein)
- [An introduction to the theory of automorphic functions](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoth00forduoft) (L Ford)
- etc.

And if you fish around there other resources all over the internet.

- [Analysis Situs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_Situs_(paper)) (Poincaré - *see link at the bottom*)

These are *books* and you asked for *journals*, but at least these are open access (no subscriptions).  In some cases you may have to chase the Journal articles from an academic library, but in many cases you don't have to hit the stacks.